# Regex jQuery - Is the url a valid xml?

Tags: jquery, regex, xml

I have to check if my url is an xml file or not with jQuery.
I have that code, but this does not work.

```
var urlPattern = /(http):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-].xml)?/

var url = $('#url').val() 

if ( urlpattern.test(url) ){
    //do something about it
}
```

Thanks !

Comment: `if ($('#url').val().slice(-4) === ".xml"){}` ? Though that would only check the extension, not the file itself

Answer (score 0):

An http URL itself can't be valid XML. There is no way to tell if the resource that a URL points to is XML without making an HTTP request to it.

If you tell `.ajax` that the `dataType` is XML it will error if it isn't.

```
jQuery.ajax(url, { dataType: "xml" })
    .done(function () { alert("Valid XML"); })
    .fail(function () { alert("Not valid XML or some other error"); })
```

[Cross-origin limitations](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Security/Same-origin_policy) apply as normal.

Comment: _"A URL itself can't be valid XML"_ OP appears to be checking for extension, or pattern in url, not if url is actual `xml` ? A `data URI` can represent a valid `xml` document; e.g.; a `data URI` of an `<svg>` document

Comment: @guest271314 — Testing to see if it has an xml extension won't tell you if it is valid XML. It probably wouldn't give many false positives, but it would give an awful lot of false negatives. The OP appears to only care about HTTP URLs, so I updated the answer to reflect that.